Redirect function is not working in nextjs 14 app
I am implementing basic authentication in a Next.js app, but redirecting to the homepage doesn`t work in the auth.ts file.
I put part of my code that implements loginForm below :
//loginForm.tsx
import { authenticate } from '../actions/auth';

export default function LogIn() {
    return (
        <form action={authenticate}>
            .
            .
            .

            <button className="mt-4 w-full" >
                Log in
            </button>
        </form>
    );
}

//auth.ts
"use server";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import createSession from "../lib/session";
import { signIn } from "../server";

export async function authenticate(formData: FormData) {
  const result = await signIn(formData);

  if (result) {
    createSession(result);
    redirect("/");
  }
}

//session.ts

import "server-only"
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export default function createSession(userId: number) {
  const expiresAt = new Date(Date.now() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  const session = `sessionIs${userId}`;

  cookies().set("session", session, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    expires: expiresAt,
    path: "/",
  });
}


I tried the code above but it didn't work, also I tried NextResponse.redirect but it didn't work too.

Hi a few question for you. Is there any errors in the console or terminal ? did you wrap your redirect with try/catch block ?

So from what I gather you created an authenticate method inside '/actions/auth'? Just to mention the 'action={authenticate}' attribute specifies where to send the form data when a form is submitted. If you'd like to execute that method rather use onSubmit.

No the code is very much a valid code using server actions

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
